# launching a local page from android webview

Tags: android, webview, getusermedia

We have created a android webview application, In the same app, we have a qr code scanner file which is located in the local directory. Due to inability to initiate camera using html5 getusermedia in android webview app, we are now trying to jump between web (webview) and local directory qr code scanner file (native) to scan the qrcode and send the data back to webview. Is it possible at the first place to do this. If yes, how do we do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by make a connection between native app and web view.

From the link which is hosted on web view you can get a callback in native app where you can do your code scanner thing, and you can pass the result to the web app(link hosted in web view) from the native app.

For detailed info u can refer [this](https://medium.com/@sreeharikv112/communication-from-webview-to-native-ios-android-app-6d842cefe02d)